# Calculating total active time from on/off activity log

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Let's pretend I have a support system. When an agent is available to handle tickets they turn themselves on. When they are no longer available, they turn themselves off. Very simple. Every time someone turns themselves on or off, the action is stored in a db table. Like so:

```
USERID    ACTION     CREATED
1         ON         2016-01-10 12:00
2         ON         2016-01-10 13:00
2         OFF        2016-01-10 15:00
1         OFF        2016-01-10 17:00
1         ON         2016-01-11 10:00
1         OFF        2016-01-11 11:00
```

In the example above, user 1 has been active for a total of 6 hours. User 2 has been active for a total of 2 hours. How would one write a query query that gives me this data, like so:

```
USERID     TOTAL
1          6 hours
2          2 hours
```

The query also needs to handle the situation where a user has turned themselves on, and are still active (just an ON action logged, no corresponding OFF).

Tbh I don't even know where to begin. I am thinking that I will probably need to create a range of timestamps and then do stuff with it. Or maybe this is just the kind of situation that is easier to deal with by writing code. Anyway, any help is appreciated.

Comment: check `LAG()` and `LEAD()` analityc function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cbeae/3)

- I add another row for `user_id = 3` with `ON` but not `OFF`
- nextAction isnt really need it, but help to see what is the `LEAD` row

**BASE QUERY:**

```
SELECT "USERID", "ACTION", "CREATED",
        LEAD("CREATED") OVER (PARTITION BY "USERID" ORDER BY "CREATED") nextDate,
        LEAD("ACTION") OVER (PARTITION BY "USERID" ORDER BY "CREATED") nextAction
FROM  activity
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| USERID | ACTION |                   CREATED |                  nextDate | nextAction |
|--------|--------|---------------------------|---------------------------|------------|
|      1 |     ON | January, 10 2016 12:00:00 | January, 10 2016 17:00:00 |        OFF |
|      1 |    OFF | January, 10 2016 17:00:00 | January, 11 2016 10:00:00 |         ON |
|      1 |     ON | January, 11 2016 10:00:00 | January, 11 2016 11:00:00 |        OFF |
|      1 |    OFF | January, 11 2016 11:00:00 |                    (null) |     (null) |
|      2 |     ON | January, 10 2016 13:00:00 | January, 10 2016 15:00:00 |        OFF |
|      2 |    OFF | January, 10 2016 15:00:00 |                    (null) |     (null) |
|      3 |     ON |    July, 08 2016 05:00:00 |                    (null) |     (null) |
```

**FINAL QUERY:**

`COALESCE(nextDate, NOW())` for the `ON` without `OFF`

```
SELECT "USERID", 
       SUM (COALESCE(nextDate, NOW()) - "CREATED") onTime
FROM (
      SELECT "USERID", "ACTION", "CREATED",
              LEAD("CREATED") OVER (PARTITION BY "USERID" ORDER BY "CREATED") nextDate,
              LEAD("ACTION") OVER (PARTITION BY "USERID" ORDER BY "CREATED") nextaction
      FROM  activity 
     ) T
WHERE   "ACTION" = 'ON'
GROUP BY "USERID"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| USERID |                                                ontime |
|--------|-------------------------------------------------------|
|      1 |        0 years 0 mons 0 days 6 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs |
|      2 |        0 years 0 mons 0 days 2 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs |
|      3 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 10 hours 47 mins 52.920889 secs |
```

Comment: All the answers do the job, but I find this to be the most elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
create table a_table (userid int, action text, created timestamp);
insert into a_table values

(1, 'ON', '2016-01-10 12:00'),
(2, 'ON', '2016-01-10 13:00'),
(2, 'OFF', '2016-01-10 15:00'),
(1, 'OFF', '2016-01-10 17:00'),
(1, 'ON', '2016-01-11 10:00'),
(1, 'OFF', '2016-01-11 11:00'),
(1, 'ON', '2016-01-11 20:00');-- added
```

Idea:

```
select distinct on (a1.userid, a1.created)
    a1.userid, a1.action, a1.created, 
    a2.userid, a2.action, a2.created, 
    coalesce(a2.created, '2016-01-11 24:00:00')- a1.created as total -- '2016-01-11 24:00:00' = the end of reported period
from a_table a1
left join a_table a2
on a1.userid = a2.userid and a1.action = 'ON' and a2.action = 'OFF' and a1.created < a2.created
where a1.action = 'ON'
order by a1.userid, a1.created, a2.created;

 userid | action |       created       | userid | action |       created       |  total   
--------+--------+---------------------+--------+--------+---------------------+----------
      1 | ON     | 2016-01-10 12:00:00 |      1 | OFF    | 2016-01-10 17:00:00 | 05:00:00
      1 | ON     | 2016-01-11 10:00:00 |      1 | OFF    | 2016-01-11 11:00:00 | 01:00:00
      1 | ON     | 2016-01-11 20:00:00 |        |        |                     | 04:00:00
      2 | ON     | 2016-01-10 13:00:00 |      2 | OFF    | 2016-01-10 15:00:00 | 02:00:00
(4 rows)
```

Query:

```
select userid, sum(total)
from (
    select distinct on (a1.userid, a1.created) 
        a1.userid, 
        coalesce(a2.created, '2016-01-11 24:00:00')- a1.created as total
    from a_table a1
    left join a_table a2
    on a1.userid = a2.userid and a1.action = 'ON' and a2.action = 'OFF' and a1.created < a2.created
    where a1.action = 'ON'
    order by a1.userid, a1.created, a2.created
) s
group by 1
order by 1;

 userid |   sum    
--------+----------
      1 | 10:00:00
      2 | 02:00:00
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT USERID, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN NOW() ELSE MAX(CREATED) END - MIN(CREATED) onTime
FROM (
  SELECT USERID, ACTION, CREATED,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'ON' THEN 1 END) OVER 
              (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY CREATED) AS grp
  FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY USERID, grp
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4cf51/2)

Answer (score 1):

Test table/data:

```
drop table if exists a_table;
create table a_table (seq serial primary key, userid int, action text, created timestamp);
create index a_table_i on a_table (userid, action, created);
insert into a_table (userid, action, created) values
(1, 'ON'  , '2016-01-10 12:00'),
(1, 'OFF' , '2016-01-10 17:00'),
(1, 'ON'  , '2016-01-11 10:00'),
(1, 'OFF' , '2016-01-11 11:00'),
(1, 'ON'  , '2016-01-11 20:00'),
(1, 'ON'  , '2016-01-11 21:00'), -- an "ON" without an "OFF"
(1, 'OFF' , '2016-01-11 21:00'),
(1, 'OFF' , '2016-01-11 22:00'), -- an "OFF" without an "ON"
(1, 'ON'  , '2016-01-11 21:10'),
(1, 'ON'  , '2016-01-11 21:20'), -- an "ON" without an "OFF"
(1, 'OFF' , '2016-01-11 21:30'),
(2, 'ON'  , '2016-01-10 13:00'),
(2, 'OFF' , '2016-01-10 15:00'),
(2, 'ON'  , '2016-01-11 13:00'),
(2, 'OFF' , '2016-01-12 15:00');
```

Query the table keeping in mind that can exists many "ON" user actions without any "OFF" (and vice-versa):

```
SELECT  USERID, SUM(FINISHED - CREATED) AS ACTIVE_TIME
FROM    (
    SELECT  *,
        -- GET THE NEXT 'OFF' ACTION RIGTH AFTER IT
        COALESCE((SELECT CREATED FROM a_table T1 WHERE T1.USERID = T.USERID AND T1.SEQ > T.SEQ ORDER BY T1.SEQ LIMIT 1),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS FINISHED
    FROM    a_table T
        -- LIST ONLY RECORDS WHERE ACTION IS 'ON' AND THE USER'S ACTION RIGHT BEFORE WAS 'OFF' OR 'NONE'
    WHERE   ACTION = 'ON'
    AND     COALESCE((SELECT ACTION FROM a_table T1 WHERE T1.USERID = T.USERID AND T1.SEQ < T.SEQ ORDER BY T1.SEQ DESC LIMIT 1),'OFF') = 'OFF'
    ) A
GROUP   BY USERID
```

Results:

```
userid   active_time
1        07:10:00
2        1 day 04:00:00
```